# Нужно ли различать производные предлоги "в завершение, по завершении"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Из словаря Ефремовой: В завершение - предл. с род.
Соответствует по значению сл.: **после чего-либо**, **под конец чего-либо**.

Вообще говоря, исходное обстоятельственное существительное (наречное выражение) "в завершение" стоит в В.п., основным значение которого является **направленность** (в данном случае на цель): чтобы завершить, завершая.  Именно эта направленность, **как мне кажется, может ограничивать** область применения этого предлога.

**Вопросы:**

1) Является ли оправданным  расширенное значение предлога "в завершение" и его свободная сочетаемость с любыми глаголами?

2) Чем отличаются предлоги **"в завершение, по завершении"** в значении "**после чего-либо**". Это полные синонимы?

2) Предлог "в завершение" со значением "**под конец чего-либо**" имеет ограниченное или неограниченное сочетание с глаголами разной семантики?

**Примеры:**

1) **В завершение беседы** Сергей Павлович сказал: «Я полностью отдаю вам «Восход-3» для проведения научных экспериментов и исследований в космосе".

Здесь правильно: чтобы завершить беседу, завершая беседу.

2) **"В завершение трюка** вся семья собиралась на манеже". Может быть, правильнее "по завершении"?

3) **"В завершение встречи** мы успели поговорить о своих планах на будущее".  Может быть, правильнее "в конце встречи"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ограничения существуют больше в смысловом отношении, чем в грамматическом. Обобщать же сочетаемость с любыми глаголами было бы рискованно и вряд ли это для чего-то полезно.
2. "**В завершение**" и "**по завершении**" имеют разный смысл. "**В завершение**" указывает на *последнее* самостоятельное действие во временных рамках упомянутого в той же фразе мероприятия (на его последнюю часть). "По завершении" указывает на то, что делается **после** того, как такое мероприятие закончилось (это *за пределами* его временных рамок).
3. Для таких обобщений требуется исследование, но в конкретных примерах обычно видно, уместно ли использовано "в завершение".

О примерах.

1. Корректное высказывание. Здесь смысл в том, что сказанное Сергеем Павловичем было последним в той беседе. Возможно, он об этом предупредил, а возможно, и нет.
2. Для меня это звучит странно, поскольку появление артистов на поклон не входит в содержание трюка. "По завершении" (= после окончания трюка) здесь подошло бы.
3. "В завершение встречи... успели" стилистически выглядит не совсем удачным - именно из-за глагола: "в завершение поговорили" или "в конце встречи успели" воспринимается нормально. Вероятно, диссонанс связан с тем, что "в завершение" безразмерно во времени - это как бы фактографический пункт повестки дня - и потому с "успеванием" не сочетается.

Comment: Но тогда получается, что значение "после чего-либо"  не соответствует предлогу "в завершение", хотя это значение указывается в словаре Ефремовой. Кроме того, предлог семантически  подходит не  к любому глаголу, потому надо продуманно применять его в речи.

Comment: Появление семьи трюкачей на манеже в полном составе ещё не означает, что это - на поклон...

Comment: Но это уже не трюк - если, конечно, он "собрались" не каким-нибудь волшебным способом (из фразы такого не следует). "В завершение своего выступления" сказать можно (оно этим завершится), поскольку это можно считать частью их выступления (как появления на публике в тот вечер), но это никак не входит в "трюк" - он к этому моменту закончен.

Comment: Пр. "в завершение" указывает на сущность сигнального действия, служащего признаком завершения какого-то действа/мероприятия. В описании встречи и беседы (Королёва с...) пр. "в завершение" свидетельствует о том, что фраза С. П. стала для участников встречи сигналом решения вопроса и окончания беседы: "Всем спасибо, все свободны". В прим. 2 нужно либо расширенно воспринимать трюк как объёмное действо, либо изменить глагол выхода-сбора (в смысле полноты состава участников), тогда предлог останется уместным (а лучше то и другое). По семантике же прим. 3 можно употребить только "в конце встречи".

Comment: Хотя можно в завершение чего и просто объявить о его окончании, "сигнальная функция" - слишком сильное обобщение. В завершение мероприятия можно предоставить кому-то слово для последней по регламенту лекции, либо можно упомянуть такими словами содержание (относительно малой) последней части чего-то прошедшего, например: "В завершение фестиваля (Вудсток '69) утром следующего дня с двухчасовым концертом выступил Джими Хендрикс. Организаторы понимали, что по завершении фестиваля предстоит грандиозная уборка мусора."